# Cant load Quantmod package in R?

Tags: r, quantmod

Every time I get ready to use my newly installed quantmod package in R I get the following:

[image]

It shows up in my library but acts as if it's not.
Even when I type remove.packages(quantmod) this shows
[image]

Im new to R, what should I do to get this package to work. I have 2 R's on my computer. One named R i386 4.0.3 and another R x64 4.0.3. Could this be an issue?

Comment: In order to use ```quantmod```, you just need to load the package. It's just your first command ```library(quantmod)```. Then you can follow this link to have an idea of what the package can do: https://www.quantmod.com/examples/intro/.

Answer (score 0):

These functions need the package name in quotation marks

```
remove.packages("quantmod")
install.packages("quantmod")
```

install.packages() installs the latest version so it can be used to update a package too

Test that it worked:

```
library("quantmod")
```

Quotation marks optional in the `library()` function

Get stock prices from GME and print them

```
GME <- getSymbols("GME", auto.assign = FALSE)

GME
```

`GME` is the object, in this case a data set of stock prices for GameStop. And `"GME"` is a literal string of characters. R can blur the distinction in functions like library() because it uses a technicque called Non-Standard Evaluation.

I'd recommend that you try RStudio, if you are new to R.
https://rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/#download